# Django 1.11 - Profile model with 1-1 link to User model

Tags: python, django

I tried to create a Profile model (a 1-1 link to User model) by following the instruction in this [blog post](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#onetoone). But something weird happened: as I create a new user, the Profile model (via the signal) generate the corresponding profiles for the user. However, it generates TWO profiles for a given user_id (which is the Django assigned id in User model). These two profiles are exactly the same except one being a well-defined integer id and one being None (please see the image below). [image: screenshot]

I googled around, but still can't figure out how come this happened.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Edit: 2018-04-10

Here is my models.py (modified from [https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#onetoone))

```
# profiles/models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class Profile(models.Model):
    # make a one-to-one conndection with User
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    service1_expire = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    product1_expire = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" %self.user.username

    # extract username and email using functions
    # this is only for disply in Admin panel (so it cannot be used as a filter)
    def username(self):
        return self.user.username

    def email(self):
        return self.user.email

    def user_id(self):
        return self.user.id

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    #if not instance.is_superuser:  # add this, so I can login into django-admin
    instance.profile.save()
```

Comment: try https://learnbatta.com/blog/using-custom-user-model-in-django-23/

Comment: Is every profile generated twice?

Comment: Could you post the model code and the code you're using for the signal handling?

Comment: @szymon Yes, every profile is generated twice (after I add Profile model into the project). Those blocked ID are the ones before I added Profile model.

Comment: @WillKeeling I just added the code in the profiles/models.py. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you comment out the second signal handler `save_user_profile()` and then you create a new user, do you still get 2 profiles created?

Comment: Hi Will, I tried your suggestion. It will simply create the one without an integer ID (the one in the bottom, please see the attached images in the original post). So it seems that the create_user_profile function not working properly. I googled around, it seems that it is kind of standard way to create a object. Any more suggestions, please?